# How to show $\|I -AX_0\|<1$, $(I -AX_0)^k\rightarrow0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix such that $\|I -AX_0\|<1$, how can we show $(I -AX_0)^k\rightarrow0$?

Is there any other way other than spectral decomposition theorem to show it? I do not want to use that.

Comment: There's nothing special about matrices here.  If $t$ is any number with $0 \le t < 1$, what can you say about $t^k$ as $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @Robert Israel: You are right, via that I was looking for proving the convergence to zero matrix. I revised the question.

Comment: $\|A\| =0 \iff A = 0$, and moreover you can show that norm convergence to $0$ means you have the limit (which is an operator) going to identically $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: since matrix norm is sub-multiplicative,
$\|(I - A X_0)^k\| \le \|I - A X_0\|^k$.